# What does this Seurat argument mean

Tags: scrnaseq, seurat, 10x-genomics

I have extensively read about `percent mito` in Seurat but I got more and more confused

Let's say we want to keep cells with `maximum 20%` of their expressed genes are mitochondrial genes, so shall I set `percent.mito < 20` or `percent.mito < 0.2` or `percent.mito < 80` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the first [Seurat tutorial](https://satijalab.org/seurat/articles/pbmc3k_tutorial.html). To filter cells with >20% mitochondrial counts:

```
obj[["percent.mito"]] <- PercentageFeatureSet(obj, pattern = "^MT-")
obj <- subset(obj, subset = percent.mito < 20)
```

Comment: I tried reading the tutorial and things are not really clear there. @Exhausted, when the tutorial says "we filter cells", they mean filtering them out i.e. removing them. So in the `subset` call, one needs to state the criteria that the data needs to pass. It's quite clear that the percent is 1-100, not 0-1 though.